# Excel VBA load picture and pause code - suspend

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with the LoadPicture Function. I want the user to push a button which opens a userform with a Picture field. In this picture field i upload every second a random picture from a folder on my computer. After ten seconds the last picture shows up and stays til the user closes the userform.

My problem is, that most of the times the first picture shows up and nothing happens after ten seconds til the last picture shows up. Seems that vba has problems with the combination of loading pictures and pause the code for 1 second.

this is my code:

```
Sub Button1_click()
Dim i,Picturename  as Integer

userform1.show
For i=1 to 10
    Randomize
    Picturename=(Int(10 * Rnd + 1)
    Userform1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\uib25432\Pictures\Foldername\" & Picturename & ".jpg")
    Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
next

End Sub
```

I'd like to know if someone has had the same problem and if there is some kind of solution for this "suspending".

Comment: Put a `DoEvents` in there before the `Application.Wait`. The form is probably just not repainting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give the form a chance to repaint.

Put a `DoEvents` after the assignment of the image (right before the `Wait`). 
If this doesn't fix the issue, you can also issue a `Repaint`-command that should force the form to repaint itself.

```
for i = 1 to 10
    ...
    Userform1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\uib25432\Pictures\Foldername\" & Picturename & ".jpg")
    UserForm1.Repaint
    DoEvents
    Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
next i
```